# How to use Qt libraries in ros

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, cmake, ros

Hi dear I'm working with Ubuntu 12.10 and ros hydro I want to use Qt libraries in ros. So I try to use simple library like "QDebug" and I write this program and Cmake

```
#include "QDebug"
#include "ros/ros.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "Qt_test");
  qDebug()<<"Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

and cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
rosbuild_add_executable(first_test src/first_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(qt_test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

but when I try to make my package with rosmake this error occured.

```
mkdir -p bin cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
.. [rosbuild] Building package qt_test 
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX:/home/hamid/working_space/qt_test/build/devel 
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:/opt/ros/hydro 
-- This workspace overlays:/opt/ros/hydro 
-- Using Debian Python package layout 
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON 
-- Skip enable_testing() for dry packages
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/hamid/working_space/qt_test/build/test_results
-- Found gtest
sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built -- catkin 0.5.77
[rosbuild] 
Including /opt/ros/hydro/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake [rosbuild]
Including /opt/ros/hydro/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/hydro/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34 (target_link_libraries): Cannot
specify link libraries for target "qt_test" which is not built by
this project.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Is there anyone help me? I know about cmake a little.Could anyone give me link for cmake that how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typo:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(first_test src/first_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(qt_test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

Make both qt_test, or both first_test.

Comment: I don't understand what you said. Could you explain more?
thanks

Comment: you inform cmake that your executable is called `first_test` and then you ask cmake to link `qt_test` with  ${QT_LIBRARIES}. cmake complains that it don't know what is `qt_test`